# Display subfolder as main folder

Tags: php, directory, mkdir, subdirectory

My main directory contains:

> 1. john (folder)
> 2. jane (folder)
> 3. james (folder)
> 4. config.php
> 5. index.php

I would like to reorganize them into:

> 1. user (folder)
> 2. config.php
> 3. index.php

WHERE the folder "user" contains:

> 1. john (folder)
> 2. jane (folder)
> 3. james (folder)

BUT keeping john's URL as `www.mydomain.com/john` AND NOT `www.mydomain.com/user/john`

Comment: Please share what you have done so far. This may be done with .htaccess.

Answer (score 1):

Which web-server do you currently use.

If Apache => use Rewrite URL http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html